# Confused over nearID, farID, nearNonce etc

Tags: flash-media-server

I am using Flash Media Server.
I am confused over various IDs
I am the nearID? And, the person on the other end is farID?
What is a nearNonce ID?

I found a high level architecture explanation that beautifully explained how P2P works overall.
Are there any more articles with detailed explanation of how all pieces fit together in the puzzle?

Finally, for peers to communicate they need to exchange peerIDs. Would using a remote shared object perform this task well or would suggest using some other kind of web service like XMPP?

Apologies for the many questions.

Answer (score 0):

FMS programming can get very confusing. To tackle you last question, typically your peers are introduced via the FMS itself - in Server Side AS. One way to do this is to have your peers connect to a NetGroup, in which case they can discover other peers connected to the same group. You can also manually introduce 2 peers in the SSAS code.

One hard lesson I learned about NetGroups is that simply being connected to a group does not mean that you will receive notification when others join the same group. You only get notified when you gain a new neighbor, which is a direct connection within the group, vs a new non-neighbor peer in the group, which is an indirect connection through other peers. If you want to know when a peer joins a group that peer should announce themselves via a group broadcast.

I'm still learning this stuff, so take this all with a grain of salt :)

Comment: Thanks Mike for taking the time and answering my question. After google for a long period I found this link which I find helpful for a novice like myself: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WScd14549950cf7821eebb00912febb43a25-8000.html

Comment: But here's  my ID problem. I have two clients connected via NetGroup.
First client has netconnection.nearId = 1b5cab71697bc852220ee2651288690d84faf11141ae8f936d6731e5bc0c97a9
Client joins NetGroup, the second client receives event: NetGroup.Neighbor.Connect event. And a value of event.info.neighbor = 9536722f1a0c5580e49ef4fedbf727325f12f96232d2c9f8a749d8271f02d712

Is there a way to figure out neighbor's peerId from event.info.neighbor?
thanks for all the help

Comment: That PDF link is talking about using multiple introduction servers, and may not be something you need when starting out.

Comment: The info object from NetGroup.Neighbor.Connect has a peerID property, so that at least is easy. Just remember that not everyone who joins the group will be your neighbor.